# module not available using requirejs+angular

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have app.js file with the following config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // vendors
        'angular': 'vendor/angular',
        'ngResource': 'vendor/angular-resource.min',
        'ngRoute': 'vendor/angular-route.min',
        'ngAnimate': 'vendor/angular-animate.min'
    },
    shim: {
        ngAnimate: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        angular: {
            deps: [],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        ngRoute: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        ngResource: {
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    },
    baseUrl: 'scripts'
});
```

Now i'm trying to instantiate angular trough require:

```
define("app", ["angular", "ngResource"], function (angular) {
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);
    // you can do some more stuff here like calling app.factory()...
    return app;
});
```

But it throws out:

```
Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I'm following [this guide](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/) step-by-step.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this file? It looks good to me. Also for some ideas on Angular-Require integration that works well with the optimizer r.js, take a look at my project [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Comment: Yes, definitely from this file. Nice project, but i'm trying to learn first how to implement simple require+angular , "by the book".

Comment: Could you then try *removing* the `ngResource` dependency and try again? It may be that (for some strange reason) `ngResource` is not loaded in time. If that is the case, we can investigate it.

Comment: You are right, removing ngResource removed the error. It's weird, i'm not getting any requirejs timeout error on ngResource file. I'll investigate further on this issue

Comment: A sanity check: Is the `angular-resource.min.js` file loaded *after* `angular.js`? Is your `main.js` loaded *after* both? The shim configuration as it is should ensure they do, but you never know...

Comment: Is it is, i'll investigate further and update when i'll find the answer. Thanks for the help